# debug assertion error

Tags: c++, debugging

I've been scratching my head for quite some time now, this code worked fine when I first used cmd to go inside the project\debug folder then run the program there. Then I added the if(in) and else part then it started giving me "debug assertion failed" errors mbstowcs.c

Expression s != NULL

It just doesn't make any sense to me..

I used this command in cmd: prog.exe test.txt nuther.txt

Both files exists inside the debug folder and the main project folder..

Any ideas?

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
        {
        parse_opts(argc, argv); //parse the arguments

        return 0;
    }


    void parse_opts(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        string compl_out;

        if( argc > 1 )
        {
            for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
            {
                if( argv[i][0] = '>' )
                {
                    ofstream out_file(argv[i+1]);
                    out_file << compl_out;
                    out_file.close();
                    break;
                }

                ifstream in(argv[i]);
                string buff;

                if(in)
                {
                    while(getline( in, buff ))
                    cout << buff << endl;

                    compl_out.append(buff); 
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Can't open file: " << argv[i] 
                            << ", file doesn't exist or is locked in use. " << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            usage();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First impressions:

```
if( argv[i][0] = '>' )
```

should be:

```
if( argv[i][0] == '>' )
```

You are assigning instead of comparing.

I think you also might have intended the **compl_out.append** to be inside the while loop?  As it is it won't append anying to that buffer:

```
while(getline( in, buff ))
{
    cout << "buf" << buff << endl;
    compl_out.append(buff); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I immediately saw that after I posted.. LOL Stupid mistakes like that are soo frustrating..

Comment: Good stuff ... Not sure why you are getting the assertion.  Unless I missed something I would expect the program to just exit given those params.  Though if you passed "blah.exe >" it could crash on the ofstream out_file(argv[i+1]); line.

Comment: A common "trick" is to write the constant expression on the right side, if you make that a habit it may save you some trouble. E.g. if ( '>' == arg[i][0] ) would be ok, if ( '>' = arg[i][0] ) would give compiler error.

Comment: @Anders That is a cool trick.  I wonder if my virtual muscle memory is too ingrained to adopt that practice.